# Where can I down load angular-material.min.js or angular-material.min.css etc

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, md-autocomplete

For now I want to use md-autocomplete in angularjs, where can I download some latest files like angular-material.min.js or angular-material.min.css

Comment: https://cdnjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out angular material's installation docs here under the **'Installing Angular Material Libraries section'** 
https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.9/getting-started

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I downloaded as your told me,

Comment: Thank you, I marked as useful answer, can you also take a look on my question of how to use md-autocomplete to keep some search history in the input textbox?  thank you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222485/how-to-use-md-autocomplete-to-keep-some-search-history-in-the-input-textbox